# Sync chroot folder with Google Drive or Dropbox in Chrome OS

Tags: dropbox, chroot, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have crouton running on a chromebook 11 with ubuntu precise in it. I am looking for a way to sync files in some folders in the ubuntu chroot with Google Drive. I am thinking I can create a link between the mounted chroot partition and a sync'ed folder in the Chrome OS, but I can't find where the synced Google Drive folder is in Chrome OS.

Could anyone please help?

Bottom line I want to sync files I create in the chroot to an online service, Google Drive or Dropbox, whatever works.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

**SUMMARY**

The best way to sync files (code, in my case) is to use git and bitbucket/github. Install git in the chroot, and sync the code into the Downloads folder so it can be accessed from both ChromeOS and the chroot (and compiled and ran locally on both computers). I stored all other files in Google Drive so they could be accessed from ChromeOS, other computers, and the chroot.

Here are the options I looked into, but did not end up using

**Accessing the Google Drive cache directly on the chromebook**

Google drive in the chrome os stores the file data in

```
/home/chronos/user/GCache/v1/files
```

However, it does not name the files how they are named in google drive (it names them by some uuid, and stores meta in another folder).

**3rd party tools to mount Google Drive folder in linux**

https://github.com/dsoprea/GDriveFS

I was able to get GDriveFS working, but it was slow and chmod does not work in its file system. The permission are all static at 666, so programs will not execute.

https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/

I was not able to get ocamlfuse working on an arm Chromebook.

https://github.com/Grive/grive

I was able to get Grive working, but it has some problems and hasn't been updated in over a year. Would not recommend if there is a chance of merge conflicts.